# Where can I find the HIPAA compliance documents or procedures to develop a web application with RESTful service?

Tags: angularjs, rest, web, hipaa

I would like to understand the HIPAA compliance to develop a  angular js framework web application for health care industry. Is there any place to get some inputs to adhere HIPAA compliance?

Comment: http://www.hhs.gov/ocr/privacy/

Comment: Thank you Dave... Is there any specific document to web development? i would like to create a check list to adhere the standards

Comment: http://www.hipaaguide.net/, http://www.slideshare.net/truevault/developers-guide-to-hipaa-compliance, http://www.ehcca.com/presentations/HIPAA7/2_04.pdf, https://luxsci.com/blog/what-makes-a-web-site-hipaa-secure.html, etc. Use Google.

Comment: Catalyze has a demo "HIPAA compliant" Angular app that might give you some clues: https://catalyze.io/blog/a-simple-hipaa-compliant-web-application-using-the-catalyze-v2-api. One thing to consider with a front-end framework is browser-caching, which is highly discouraged when handling PHI.